# About the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\mathrm{BB}(n)}$

Tags: lo.logic

Let $\mathrm{BB}:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be the busy beaver function. Eventually $\mathrm{BB}(n)>n^2$ so the sum$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\mathrm{BB}(n)}$$converges.

> **Question.** What is the largest rational number $q$ such that $S\geq q$ is not known to be inconsistent with ZFC?

Comment: Which definition of BB(n) are you using?

Comment: @JoshuaZ the definition in https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/bb.pdf on page 2

Comment: Since BB(5) is not known, probably 1/BB(1)+1/BB(2)+1/BB(3)+1/BB(4)+1/(our best bound for BB(5))

Comment: "Eventually $BB(n) > n^2$ . . . " Yes, that's putting it mildly. :)

Comment: Adding on to Wojowu's comment slightly: thanks to how fast $BB(n)$ grows, we know that the first several decimal places of this constant are $1.2236315$. The next (at least) 36000 decimal places depend only on the value of $BB(5)$, which we do not yet know.

Comment: @NathanielJohnston could you make your comment into an answer?